# Python: Some float (strings) convert to integers, others don't

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

Why do some floats convert to integers and others don't in this Python code?

I've tested the following code with various floats as input (e.g. 11.1, 11.5, 44.5, 22.5, etc.) and sometimes the code returns, for example, "x is 11" and sometimes it returns "x is not an integer." Why?

```
    def main():
        x = get_int("What's x? ")
        print (f'x is {x}')

    def get_int(prompt):
        while True:
            try:
                return int(input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                print("x is not an integer.")
            try:
                return int(float(input(prompt)))
            except ValueError:
                print("x is not an integer.")
            else:
                return x

    main()
```

Comment: Follow the flow.  You call `get_int`.  For input, you supply `11.1`.  That is NOT an integer, so you'll get the ValueError and print "x is not an integer".  You then flow into the SECOND `input` function, where you type 11.5, and that works.   I don't think you want to ask AGAIN here.  You should ask once, store the result, then try as an integer, and if that doesn't work, try as a float.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you were thinking of.  If it works as an integer return it.  Otherwise, try that SAME STRING as a float.

```
def main():
    x = get_int("What's x? ")
    print (f'x is {x}')

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        i = input(prompt)
        try:
            return int(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("x is not an integer.")
        try:
            return int(float(i))
        except ValueError:
            print("x is not a float.")
        else:
            return x

main()
```

Comment: Of course, just *one* `int(float(i))` would do exactly the same thing…

Comment: @deceze Until someone enters an integer not representable as `float`.

Comment: @Stuart *Almost all* integers cannot be represented as a `float`. Smallest positive example: 9007199254740993

Answer (score 0):

On line number 8 the `input()` will only accept text of type `int`. Therefore if you input a `float` it will throw a `ValueError`. But on line number 12 the input is being converted to a `float` then it is being converted to an `int`. Which does not throw a `ValueError`.